# SqlXml not taking responsibility for disposing of MemoryStream

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

I was looking doing a code review today whereby someone one attempting to dispose of a `MemoryStream` by wrapping it up in a `using` block. In this case it was being passed into a `SqlXml` instance, and I wasn't sure what it did with it, so I took a quick look at the decompiled source. Here's the example code:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data)) {
   var param = new SqlXml(ms);
   var parameter = new SqlParameter("@Xml", System.Data.SqlDbType.Xml) { Value = param };
   command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}

return command;
```

Here is the decompiled source:

```
public SqlXml(Stream value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        this.SetNull();
    }
    else
    {
        this.firstCreateReader = true;
        this.m_fNotNull = true;
        this.m_stream = value;
    }
}
```

Now best practice says that the `SqlXml` should now take responsibility for disposing of this stream. But unfortunately it doesn't implement `IDisposable`.

On top of this I don't know when the `SqlCommand` containing it is going to get consumed and `SqlXml` is sealed, so I can realistically extend it.

Can anyone suggest a good approach for handling this? I'm planning on logging a bug somewhere with Microsoft because it's not a very nice thing to have to workaround.

My best suggestion at the moment is to use the constructor that takes an `XmlReader` because it at least copies the contents, so the reader can then be disposed - however internally that just creates a `MemoryStream` and never cleans it up either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing to remember when implementing `IDisposable` is DO NOT dispose of `IDisposable` instances that you do not "own" (those which your class has not specifically created). So TL;DR, it wouldn't be a good idea for `SqlXml` to implement `IDisposable` since it didn't create the underlying `Stream`.

Answer (score 0):

SqlXml certainly should not dispose the memory stream: it is passed it by its (unknown) caller who may well have further use of it. SqlXml doesn't own the stream, and it may well break the caller if it does dispose it so it should leave alone after putting it where it's needed.